# saveBackStack FragmentTransactions must use setReorderingAllowed(true). Found BackStackEntry{} that did not use setReorderingAllowed(true)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigationview

A HomeActivity class has a bottom menu navigation which opens up a fragment class. Everything is good to navigate inside the fragment class. However, when I click any other bottom menu navigation item from this fragment class, it immediately crashes and results with the below error,

```
2022-12-07 10:39:41.828  8956-8956  AndroidRuntime pid-8956
E FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.my.app.debug, PID: 8956 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: saveBackStack("f1a147ba-4bb3-449c-87b8-cf73f7bf463c") included 
FragmentTransactions must use setReorderingAllowed(true) to ensure that the back stack can be
restored as an atomic operation. 
Found BackStackEntry{82b1a #1} that did not use setReorderingAllowed(true).

at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.saveBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:2141)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$SaveBackStackState.generateOps(FragmentManager.java:3494)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.generateOpsForPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2067)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1757)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

In my fragment class, I tried to return the same view in onCreateView()

```
if (fragmentView != null) {
            return fragmentView;
}
```

Also added 'context' in onResume() for my fragment class

```
var mContext: FragmentActivity? = FragmentActivity()

mContext = this!!.getActivity() as HomeActivity

mContext.bottomItems()
```

and nothing worked so far. With this log information couldn't find much on where and what exactly went wrong.

I found this Stack overflow link [app-crashes-when-tapping-multiple-times-on-bottom-navigation-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608600/app-crashes-when-tapping-multiple-times-on-bottom-navigation-views) that somewhat relates to my issue however the error between mine and this link is different here

```
Found BackStackEntry{82b1a #1} that did not use setReorderingAllowed(true).
```

**Adding Code**
For Understanding, From Home screen user clicks the bottom navigation which shows the FirstFragment screen. The Firstfragment contains few tabviews where you see the SecondFragment information called in `observeResponse()` method in the class `FirstFragment.kt` being called will get loaded.

*HomeActivity.kt*

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var sfHelper: SharedPrefHelper
    private var mCacheManager: CacheManager? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mCacheManager = CacheManager(this)
        sfHelper = SharedPrefHelper(this)

        val mainActivityIntent: Intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        mainActivityIntent.putExtra("navigateScreen", intent.getStringExtra("navigateScreen"))
        startActivity(mainActivityIntent)
        finishAffinity()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)
        try {
          navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment_container) 
          appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.homeFragment)
                                .setDrawerLayout(main_drawer_layout)  
                                .build()
          if (mCacheManager!!.isShortCut()) {
                    when (mCacheManager!!.getShortCutName()) {
                      "firstFrag" -> {
                                navController.navigate(R.id.homeFragment_to_firstFragment)
                                ClearCache.cacheManagerClear(this)
                      }
                    }
          }
          } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
    }

    private fun setupNavControl() {
        bottom_navigation?.setupWithNavController(navController)
        main_navigation_view?.setupWithNavController(navController)

    }

    private fun showBothNavigation() {
        bottom_navigation?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        main_navigation_view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        main_drawer_layout?.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
        setupNavControl()
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean { 
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        when {
            main_drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START) -> {
                main_drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            }
            else -> {
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

*HomeFragment.kt*

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    private lateinit var appContext: Context
    private var fragmentView: View? = null
    lateinit var sharedPref: SharedPrefHelper

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        if (fragmentView != null) {
            return fragmentView;
        }
        sharedPref = SharedPrefHelper(context as Activity)
        val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        fragmentView = view
        return view
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        loadViewCreated()
    }

    private fun loadViewCreated() {
        try {
            sharedPref = SharedPrefHelper(context as Activity)
            appContext = (context as Activity).applicationContext
            if (user == true) {
                cButton.setOnClickListener(this)
                Glide.with(context as Activity).load(R.drawable.preloader_gif).into(loadingViewHome)
            } else {
                maLogger.info("HomeFragment", "onViewCreated", "MainApplication.model is null")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            maLogger.error("HomeFragment", "onViewCreated", e.message.toString())
            ExceptionHandler.errorHandle(context as Activity, e.message.toString())
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v!!.id) {
            R.id.cButton -> {
                Navigation.findNavController(v)
                    .navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.homeFragment_to_firstFragment())
            }
        }
    }


    fun observeModel(viewModel: HomeViewModel) {
        viewModel.response.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                if (activeUser == true) {
                
                }
                  
            }
       }
    }
}
```

*FirstFragment.kt*

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    lateinit var cView: View
    private lateinit var cViewModel: CViewModel
    private var isRotating: Boolean = false
    private lateinit var rViewModel: rViewModel
    private lateinit var sfHelper: SharedPrefHelper
    var user = false

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, @Nullable container: ViewGroup?, @Nullable
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        retainInstance = true
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            sfHelper = SharedPrefHelper(context as Activity)
            cView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
        }
        return cView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true

        if (sfHelper!!.getValueBoolean("SORTING", defaultValue = false) == true) {
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                loadData()
            } else {
                if (MainApplication.isRotating == 1) {
                    loadData()
                }
            }
        } else {
            sortingPopUp()
        }
    }

    private fun sortingPopUp() {
        val mDialog = Dialog(context as Activity, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar)
        mDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0)))
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sorting)
        mDialog.setCancelable(false)
        mDialog.show()

        mDialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_got_it).setOnClickListener {
            sfHelper.save("SORTING", true)
            mDialog.dismiss()
            if (NetworkConnectivity.checkNetwork(context as Activity)) {
                loadData()
            } else {
                ExceptionHandler.noInternetAlert(context as Activity)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        if (MainApplication.backClick == 1 || MainApplication.isRotating == 1) {
            var mContext: FragmentActivity? = FragmentActivity()

            mContext = this!!.getActivity() as HomeActivity

            mContext.bottomItems()
        }
        rViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(rViewModel::class.java)

        try {
            var cList = MainApplication.switchList
            if (MainApplication.isActive) {
                if (MainApplication.active_model != null) {
                
                }
            } else {

            }
            if (cList.size != null) {
                for (i in 0 until cList.size) {
                    try {

                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }


    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v!!.id) {

        }
    }

    private fun observeResponse() {
      try {
            cViewModel.response.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                it?.let {

                
                        fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
                            ?.replace(R.id.root_container, SecondFragment())
                            ?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit()
                    }


                })
        }
         catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        if (isRotating) {
            MainApplication.isRotating = 1
            outState.putBoolean("isRotating", true)
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (MainApplication.backClick == 1) {
            isRotating = true
            loadData()
        } else if (MainApplication.isRotating == 1) {
            isRotating = true
            loadData()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        var mContext: FragmentActivity? = FragmentActivity()

        mContext = this!!.getActivity() as HomeActivity

        mContext.bottomItems()
        if (MainApplication.backClick == 1) {
            root_container.removeAllViews()
            MainApplication.backClick = 0

        }
        if (MainApplication.isRotating == 1) {
            root_container.removeAllViews()
            MainApplication.isRotating = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message says you are doing a `FragmentTransaction` that didn't call `setReorderingAllowed(true)`, but you haven't included any of your code that does your fragment transactions for your bottom nav. Can you include your activity's code?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Please find the activity and fragment code from Adding Code section above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should never, ever be doing a `FragmentTransaction` to go to a new screen when using a `NavController`: you should be calling `navigate`. Why are you doing a `FragmentTransaction` in `FirstFragment` at all?

Comment: @ianhanniballake You are right. Just fixing other people work. For now, looking for a patch work to fix before I start rewriting these.